# How do I adjust the tap-to-click sensitivity on the Magic Trackpad or the built-in MacBook trackpad?

Tags: magic-trackpad

I have the tap-to-click feature enabled on my Magic Trackpad and find that it works very well for the most pat. However, I think it tends to be a little too sensitive at times. Is there any secret adjustment for reducing the tapping sensitivity of the Magic Trackpad? I assume that the same setting will also apply to the built-in trackpad on MacBooks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the sensitivity of the tap-to-click feature on the trackpad may not be adjusted through the default system software at present. It may only be turned off altogether.

However if you download [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.net) it will allow you to adjust tap sensitivity, among other things.

Comment: There does NOT seem to be a setting for single-finger taps in BTT, no?

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. BTT cannot control the sensitivity settings for system gestures.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer
Use BetterTouchTool. Under the Advanced Trackpad->Taps setting is an option to adjust the time and pressure sensitivity for three and four finger taps

Comment: How is your answer a complete answer?  what we're looking for is how to adjust single (the most frequently used) tap.  Your answer doesn't provide that information.